# Angular v10 and Material Datepicker v10, add customer attribute to cdk-overlay tag

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I'm working with Angular v10 and Material v10 and try to add custom attribute to the cdk-overlay element with cladd 'cdk-overlay-pane mat-datepicker-popup', but unable to find any method or way to add new attributes to that element. I reviewd the [Material Datepicker v10 API](https://v10.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) docs and saw method getConnectedOverlayOrigin, but was not able to find any example. There are few suggestion to add custom attribute to mat-datepicker-toggle tag, but that dosent have any effect on cdk-overlay element

[image]

[Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-starter-project-daidh-bupvf5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,package.json)

Comment: I don't think you can. You can apply a class to the picker itself, but not the overlay. If you need to customize the overlay, your best bet is creating a custom control that will create new `cdk-overlay` on click, and insert `mat-calendar` into that overlay. I don't think `mat-calendar` is documented in v10 docs, but interfaces should be similar to what they have in v12 docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a class to the "mat-calendar" you use `panelClass`

```html
<mat-datepicker #picker panelClass="custom"></mat-datepicker>
```

If you want to "reach" the cdk-overlay you can use document.getElementsByClassName in the event opened

```html
<mat-datepicker #picker 
  panelClass="custom" 
  (opened)="reachOverPanel()">
</mat-datepicker>
```

```js
reachOverPanel() {
  const elem = document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-overlay-pane')[0]
  elem.setAttribute('aria-label','fool')
  console.log(elem)
}
```

Curiosity: What are you trying do?

Comment: the overlay config dose provide properties to add custom classes, but nothing that would target the div with 'cdk-overlay-#'. As per Accessibility requirement modal div should have aria-label attribute.

Comment: Issue: the work around would be grab the element after the date picker is opened and then set the attribute, however, the elementRef is always null, any clue?

setTimeout(() => {
      const overLayEle = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div.cdk-overlay-pane.mat-datepicker-popup');
      if (overLayEle) {
        overLayEle.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Select Date');
      }
    }, 1000);

Comment: It's not necesary "wait" 1000 miliseconds. In Angular, when you use setTimeout makes that the function is executed after "repaint". Using the property event you can avoid this "repaint". I use `opened` event because this event is dispatched after is open.